# Custom fields within fieldset are not visible in VF page

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, fields

I want to display all the fields field set but out of 4 it is displaying only 1 which standard field I am not able to display the custom field form field set.

> Schema.FieldSetMember[getDbRequired=false;getFieldPath=Contact__c;getLabel=Contact;getRequired=false;getType=REFERENCE;], 
>   Schema.FieldSetMember[getDbRequired=false;getFieldPath=Name;getLabel=Project Name;getRequired=false;getType=STRING;], 
>   Schema.FieldSetMember[getDbRequired=false;getFieldPath=Start_Date__c;getLabel=Start Date;getRequired=false;getType=DATE;], 
>   Schema.FieldSetMember[getDbRequired=false;getFieldPath=End_Date__c;getLabel=End Date;getRequired=false;getType=DATE;])

This is the debug result where I am getting all the fieldset value but only 1 getFieldPath=Name;getLabel=Project is getting displayed which is a standard field but other all are custom fields so it is not getting displayed. Can anyone help me out what is the reason behind it? 
My Vf page :

```
<apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filter Project">
          <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="f">
              <apex:outputLabel value="{!pjt_fieldSet[f.label]}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!pjt_fieldSet[f.fieldPath]}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: A guess would be to make sure your api version is 31.0. It maybe that these are new fields created after the VF page was created.

Comment: yes the version is 31.0 and the fields where there before the VF page was created.  I created the field first after that i created the VF page.

Comment: Not able to understand why this issue come i tried by making the object as standardcontroller even this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi it was my fault sorry. The field was hidden for the profile. Security issue.